# Cómo traducir una propiedad con parámetros de VB.Net a C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

He estado tratando de pasar este código que esta en VB.net a C#

```
Public Property Clases(ByVal indice As Long) As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Clases(indice)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        _Clases(indice) = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Pero al momento de usar algún traductor me entrega este código

```
public bool Clases
{
  private get
  {
    return _Clases(indice);
  }

  private set
  {
    _Clases(indice) = Value;
  }
}
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto en visual studio me genera error
Que estaria mal??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En C# no se pueden definir [propiedades con parámetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/property-procedures) como en VB.NET, con la excepción de un [indizador](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/), pero eso no es exactamente lo mismo.  La forma usual de traducir lo que tienes a C# es simplemente creando 2 métodos normales para hacer el *get* y el *set*. (Nota que cambié el tipo del índice de `long` a `int`, porque según tu comentario, parece que `_Clases` no es más que un `bool` array. No hay necesidad que sea `long`):

```
public class MiClase
{
    public bool GetClases(int indice)
    {
        return _Clases[indice];
    }

    public void SetClases(int indice, bool valor)
    {
        _Clases[indice] = valor;
    }
}
```

Si deseas usar un indizador, puedes escribirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
public class MiClase
{
    public bool this[int indice]
    {
        get
        {
            return _Clases[indice];
        }

        set
        {
            _Clases[indice] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

... pero entonces la forma de acceder a ella no sería igual a como lo harías en VB.NET, porque el indizador no tiene nombre. Ejemplo:

```
var instancia = new MiClase();
bool valor = instancia[10]; // leer
instancia[10] = valor; // escribir
```

Comment: la variable esta definida de la siguiente manera
 Private _Clases(45) As Boolean

Comment: O sea que es un simple arreglo de `bool`. En ese caso, cambia el tipo del índice de `long` a `int`. No hay necesidad de que tu indice sea un `long`. De hecho, tal vez te cause problemas. Pero por lo demás, debería ser tal cual te lo puse.